# docker push to non-TLS registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am deploying my own docker registry and during testing I want to `docker push` to an non-TLS registry at `local:8000`. However, I get the following:

```
$ docker push local:8000/alexflint/kayak-test-foo
The push refers to a repository [local:8000/alexflint/kayak-test-foo]
Get https://local:8000/v1/_ping: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

My understanding is that the docker client is expecting to be talking to an HTTPS server, but my server is serving HTTP. Is there any way to tell `docker push` to use HTTP?

The docker client I am using is Docker for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Docker for Mac menubar icon -> Preferences -> Advanced -> add "local:8000" as an insecure registry:

[image]

Then click "Apply & Restart"